# Show that there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ for which $\phi(n)^2 + n^2$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

The problem at the title is one of my elementary number theory exercises.

I attempted to find a specific form of $n$ which satisfies the condition. I tried $n = p$ (prime) and $n = p^k$ case, but those two do not yield the answer. I also tried $n = pq$ case, but I was not able to decide that this works or not, since the expression gets too complicated.

Please help me if you know the form of $n$ which makes $\phi(n)^2 + n^2$ a perfect square. Thank you for any helps, answers, and hints.

Comment: What are the options of the form for the two smaller elements of a Pythagorean triple?

Comment: @MarkBennet To use the form of a Pythagorean triple, then $n$ must be square-free since $\gcd(\phi(n), n)$ should be $1$. So for $s,t$ such that $\gcd(s,t)=1$, $s>t$, $s \not\equiv t \pmod{2}$, $n = s^2-t^2$ and $\phi(n)=2st$ since the value of totient function should be even. But this does not give me a clue. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n=3^k\cdot 5$ for $k\ge 1$. Then we have $\phi(n)=8\cdot 3^{k-1}$, and hence
$$
n^2+\phi(n)^2=3^{2k}\cdot 5^2+8^2\cdot 3^{2k-2}=(3^{k-1})^2(9\cdot 5^2+8^2)=(17\cdot 3^{k-1})^2.
$$
This holds for all $k\ge 1$, so that we have infinitely many $n$ with $n^2+\phi(n)^2=c^2$.